# Timeout error when accessing WCF service remotely

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, amazon-ec2, topshelf

When I access the WCF service locally it works. To do this I type into my browser: http://localhost:54123/MyService/GetValue

This shows my expected json formatted output. However, when accessing remotely using http://myIPAddress:54123/MyService/GetValue I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT in Chrome.

I have my inbound IP whitelisted for all TCP ports, so I am not sure why I would be unable to access remotely. This is being hosted on an amazon EC2 instance if that makes any difference.

Here is the code I have in my main() method for hosting the service via Topshelf

```
    const string serviceUri = "http://localhost:54123/MyService";
    var host = HostFactory.New(configurator =>
    {
        configurator.Service<WcfServiceWrapper<MyServiceClass, IMyServiceClass>>(serviceConfigurator =>
        {
            serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(x =>
                new WcfServiceWrapper<MyServiceClass, IMyServiceClass>("MyService", serviceUri));
            serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted(service => service.Start());
            serviceConfigurator.WhenStopped(service => service.Stop());
        });
        configurator.RunAsLocalSystem();

        configurator.SetDescription("Runs My Service.");
        configurator.SetDisplayName("MyService");
        configurator.SetServiceName("MyService");
    });
```

Here is the relevant code from my WcfWrapper start() method

```
var webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.None);
    _serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TServiceContract), webHttpBinding, _serviceUri);

    var webHttpBehavior = new WebHttpBehavior
    {
        DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
    };
    _serviceHost.Description.Endpoints[0].Behaviors.Add(webHttpBehavior);

    _serviceHost.Open();
    openSucceeded = true;
```

Below is what I have in my config file

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="MyServiceClassNS.MyServiceClass">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://myIPAddress:54123/MyService"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall turned on?

Comment: Apparently I do, I added an inbound rule with my port number and now it appears to be working. I thought that the security rule in AWS was enough to cover this, but there is also a Windows Firewall running in this case. Thank you, you should elevate this to the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely cause of the problem is that the firewall is blocking the call.